# Spring Boot: Exclude configuration properties for profiles from jar package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application for which I keep a base `application.properties`, and then a couple of `application-${profile}.properties` files with configuration valid for several development environments.

I want to keep those `application-${profile}.properties` files in source control, but as they contain private development environment details, I want to be able to create a `jar` package without them for distribution to third parties (i.e. only with the base `application.properties`). This would force users to add their own `application.properties` to the classpath when executing (or configure in other ways), which is what I intend.

I understand I could move those *profile configuration* files elsewhere instead of `src/main/resources` so that `mvn package` ignores them, then add such folder to the classpath in IDE configurations... but I think there probably is a more integrated, elegant way of doing this with Boot that I'm missing...

Comment: Have you thought of a Configuration server ? it is easy to set up using Spring boot

Comment: @zakariaamine well yes, but I wanted to avoid going that far... thanks!

Comment: I think you can pass arguments during the running of the jar which can override the values in the properties file. [Externalizing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: @Diyoda_ yes, but there are several parameters so that would be uncomfortable. And I definitely want those parameters in the (internal) SCM, so an `application-${profile}.properties` is more fitting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done it myself but according to the documentation, the application is reading properties from following locations

1. A `/config` subdirectory of the current directory.
2. The current directory A classpath `/config` package
3. The classpath root

Then you can do

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=nameofpropertiesfile
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something. You're right. All the `application-${profile}.properties` go to `/config`, the IDE recognizes them (when the profile is adequately set), and they don't go into the `.jar`. Bootiful ;). Thanks so much!